# Ошибка при создании архива приложения ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Здравствуйте. До того, как обновлял xcode, все было нормально, но сейчас написал приложение, собирался сделать архив и проверить его перед отправкой, я получаю множестве ошибок. Я так понимаю, эти ошибки говорят о том, что у меня не хватает сертификатов, но я заходил в Member Center, там вроде все есть. Может кто-нибудь пошагово написать что делать? Очень бы помогли. 
Картинка с ошибками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании App IDs в developer.apple.com Вам необходимо включить нужные компоненты. В Вашем случае это iCloud. После чего не забыть в xcode правильно указать созданный prov.profiles. Если у Вас уже есть App IDs, то его можно отредактировать и включить нужные компоненты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так, как показано на скрине я включаю, выбирая xcode 6. А вот с prov.profiles я ничего не делаю, просто обновляю свой профиль и все. Как указывать сертификат в xcode? Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @ed8009 у Вас Bundle Identifier в Xcode указан такой же, как и в App IDs? Что значит вы включаете в Xcode 6 как на скрине? Вам надо включать iCloud  не только в Xcode, но и при создании App IDs, как я показал на скрине. У Вас ошибка из-за того, что Вы включаете iCloud в Xcode, а в app IDs у вас не включен

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что устанавливаю как на скрине второй вариант с xcode 6. Вот скрин того, что iCloud подключен: (http://cs628831.vk.me/v628831778/2a57/II5gdj-FZSY.jpg)

В Xcode установлен такой же App IDs, вот скрин (http://cs628831.vk.me/v628831778/2a5f/TkoskzQXpv4.jpg)

Comment: @ed8009 все верно. После того, как Вы включили iCloud в App IDs, Вы должны создать Provisioning Profiles c этим App IDs для AppStore (Distribution). Скачать его. Нажать два раза на скаченный файл, чтобы он добавился в проект. И попробовать снова отправить Ваш проект в AppStore.

Comment: Получается, что нужно создать две сертификата: Development и Distribution?

Comment: @ed8009  верно! Один служит для заливки проекта на "живое" устройство (Development). Другой нужен для заливки проекта в AppStore (Distribution)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы даже и не представляете сколько радости подарили мне! Все заработало

Comment: @ed8009 рад был помочь! Удачи Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Попробуйте зайти в **Xcode**->**Preferences**->**Accounts** открыть свой аккаунт, кликнув на него дважды, и в появившемся окне нажать кнопку обновить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: обновить]

Comment: Да, уже проделывал подобное, не помогает

Comment: Мне помогает в таких случаях еще и переоткрыть проект. А лучше Xcode перезапустить.

Comment: Если отключить iCloud, то все прекрасно работает и архивируется, но как только включить, то сразу летят ошибки, мне больше кажется, что дело в сертификатах.